# custom resharper rule to format imports

Tags: c#, format, resharper

I have a c# class library project and we have a rule that forces us to split the usings in two parts, first part is System.* usings and the other part are the rest of usings (each art is ordered alfabetically). Is there a way to enforce resharper formatter to format my code in this way?

Here is the expected result of the formatting rule:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

using MyNamespace;
using MyNamespace.Test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you need is Extensions > ReSharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Blank Lines > Blank Lines In Declarations > Between different "using" groups.

Consider using formatting options autodetection. Select a code block formatted as you want (desired formatting) by hand, Alt-Enter > Format Selection > Detect formatting settings. [image]